# Bootstrap v2.3.2 - Hide modal then reopen with fresh content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to save modal content and on successfully saving I want to close the modal then reopen it with empty form fields.

Everything is working except for reopening the modal...

Here's the code I have.

```
$('#modal-footer .add-another').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('/save', $('form').serialize(), function(data){
        $('#edit_modal').modal('hide');
        $("#edit_modal").on('hidden', function() {
            $("#edit_modal").modal({
                remote: '/form/'
            });
        });
    });

    return false;
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
$.post('/save', $('form').serialize(), function(data){
        $('#edit_modal').modal('hide');
        $("#edit_modal").on('hidden', function() {
            $("#edit_modal").modal({
                remote: '/form/'
            });
        });
        $('form')[0].reset();//Reset the form if in current page
        $('#edit_modal').modal('show');//Open the modal
    });
```

Comment: The need to reset the form elements is irrelevant because remotely loading the modal content does this anyway. So the problem of it not reopening remains